Max diameter of a water pipe acting like a straw
I have a pipe (PE) filled with water, one end of which is raised up, the other is lowered down and closed with a valve. In the middle, the pipe has a "sag", the level of which is slightly higher than the level of the valve.
Obviously, if the diameter of the pipe is comparable to a straw, when the valve is opened, all the water will be pushed out of the pipe by atmospheric pressure.
But if the pipe diameter is, say, 1 meter, the water will not be pushed out of the sagging zone completely, only from its upper part.
Is it possible to roughly estimate what would the maximum diameter of the pipe be (1", 1/2" etc.) for it to yet act like a "straw" (to push all the water out of it completely)?


Called a syphon - seen it on (" and 10" pipes. many cases can be found if you look.

Speaking of classic siphon, like in this wikipedia picture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lappo.svg) with sufficient flow it can be of any pipe diameter (you just don't want to let air bubbles in from the lower end like in a two-way movement where water goes down and air goes up, so you provide the flow to prevent air to get in the pipe from below). My case is a bit different, because here the air gets into the pipe from the upper end, so, how fast do you suck water doesn't matter anymore.
